# Disturbance in AC adapter

Tags: simulation, adapter

I'm studying AC adapters, and to check about waveforms while changing parameters I did a simulation of this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flTN8P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then I wanted to plot also the rectified waveform, so I added a second diode and a big resistance (sorry if this circuit doesn't use the internal CAD, but I was unable to find how to insert two schematics: if I tried to insert a second one, the first was deleted):

[image]

so on the 1G resistance there should be the rectified voltage, and the resistance should be big enough to not influence the circuit.

It seems to work, but what I don't understand is that there seem to be a disturbance on the secondary of the transformer, and on the rectified waveform (green on the left graph is the primary of the transformer):

[image]

So the secondary voltage has the positive part of the wave distorted, and the negative which is thicker, like there was some very rapid oscillation; and the rectified wave has the same distortion.

I tried experimenting with the simulation, and it seems to be due to the capacitor, since if I delete it the waveforms are a non distorted sines and the rectified waveform with no distortion; I'm not sure if this is something real, or an error of the simulator.

As for the diode, there is a parameter I don't know ("Current At Above Voltage"), but their model as given in the simulator is:

- saturation current: 171 nA
- forward voltage: 806 mV (but the distortion are the same with 0)
- current at above voltage: 1 A
- emission coefficient: 2

Are those distortions something to be expected? If so, why?

As simulator I used [Circuit JS](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html).

Comment: This is LC distortion from the transformer and the cap.  It's common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Are those distortions something to be expected? If so, why?*

The disturbance at the top of the positive peak is fundamental to any practical rectifier and smoothing capacitor. Once the capacitor has charged to a significant voltage, the diode won't conduct to inject more charge into the capacitor until the diode's anode voltage has reached slightly above the charged capacitor voltage. At that point, a sudden injection of current occurs and this can be quite high in peak value.

The net result is that the impulse of current causes significant volt-drops in the transformer and diode resulting in the waveform distortion you see. If you also plotted diode current you would see what I mean.

I expect that the high frequency artefacts you get are as a result of the simulator although, there will be some ringing due to parasitic inductance in a real circuit - maybe you have a bit of both - it all depends entirely on your models.

Comment: I plotted the current, thanks: https://i.imgur.com/CXdpoat.png.

Comment: @Mauro so, has this answered your concerns?

Comment: It did, thanks.